# Multiple RGB string to color boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Basically i have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfjnf5r3/),

As you can see on the fiddle there is a long string of numbers ( they are an rgb code)

You can see that there also is just one box inside mydiv (totally forgot to add the others in for the palette).

Basically i need all the other RGB codes to have their own box to show the colors that the RGB represents.

Here is the code for you none JS Fiddlers

HTML

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    <h3>Make a Custom Theme from your image</h3>
    <p> Based on your logo we believe this is the best colour scheme for you</p>
    <div id="mydiv" style="background-color: rgb({{dominantColor}})"></div>
    <h4>{{palette}}</h4>
    <h4>
        [[59,214,252],[217,236,252],[14,137,250],[4,31,156],[43,188,251],[13,86,199],[107,162,231],[53,117,204],[61,159,245]]
    </h4> <!-- This is whats returned via the {{palette}} -->
    <p>is this correct?</p>
    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>-->
</div>
```

Css

```
#mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I'm expecting to use JS to split up the codes, I can return the data without the square brackets `[]` So in theory i need the js to grab each rgb code and display the colour inside the box.

Comment: Did you forget to add the JS in your fiddle? :o

Comment: Nope don't have any js so i cant add js if i have none haha!!

Comment: So what's your question ?

Comment: How do i split up the RGB code to use in multiple divs, e.g. `[59,214,252]` in one div and `[217,236,252]` in another div etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half baked jsfiddle doesn't help much, really. Fiddle is for working example so we can see the existing condition and debug right away, not for you to paste your code for people to read.

Please refer to the snippet for solution. You can use `ng-style` to dynamically place the rgb values as css style.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [[59,214,252],[217,236,252],[14,137,250],[4,31,156],[43,188,251],[13,86,199],[107,162,231],[53,117,204],[61,159,245]];
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div class='box' ng-style="{'background-color': 'rgb('+color[0]+', '+color[1]+', '+color[2]+')'}" ng-repeat='color in data'></div>
</div>
```